# Generating triplets of letters in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, loops, unique

I am struggling with the following task:

> Let's take a look at sets of three small letters (e.g. aaa, aab, etc.). Having an input a natural number N, print out the first N sets with unique letters in each of them.
>
> Example:
>
> input: 5
> output: abc abd abe abf abg

How can I write the algorithm?

Comment: It sounds like a homework question... The rules of the site is that you should ask a specific technical question, what did you try that didn't work, or what concept don't you understand?

Comment: Hi Mira, welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a coding service, take a look at [tour]. Please show what you have tried and ask a specific technical question if you have one.

Comment: Hello guys, 
I have tried a few concepts that came to my mind but I couldn't quite figure out how to generate 3 different letters especially if the input is a number bigger than 24. Should i necessarily use a string or is there any alternative?

Comment: Perhaps you could [add what you've tried to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59001739/edit)? Then maybe we can help you figure out where you're going wrong.

Comment: Mira, could you show _in the question itself_ what you have tried? Even if you have tried a small thing, it shows readers that you have considered the problem before posting here, and readers appreciate that a great deal.

Comment: I would add also that there is some negative feedback on this question, both in comments and downvotes. Don't take it personally! We see hundreds of homework questions a day, and many of them have no prior work - so while you may well have tried something, we have to be strict about it in order to preserve clear, focussed questions that will be useful to other programmers in the future. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems like a homework question, I'll go through some length and explain how the code below works.

Imagine having a similar task to write out characters from `a..z`, you would go through all of them and stop at a point once you reach the number you'd like. So a code like this will do that for you

```cpp
for (char c='a'; c <= 'z'; c++) { /* ... */ }
```

This will yield you the result of `abcd...z` Now, in order to get what you need, you need to imagine the output of this loop as a column, so to yield 
the output you want you need to do something like:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
...
...
...
zzz
```

So you need to think along the lines of: "for every character I need to get every character and for that character every character"

HINT: this can be achieved by setting up 3 for loops.

I strongly discourage opting in for the solution first, but in case you still get stuck, feel free to use it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int n, totalIterations;
  std::cin >> n;

  totalIterations = 0;
  for (char i='a'; i <= 'z'; i++) {
    for (char j='a'; j <= 'z'; j++) {
      for (char z='a'; z <= 'z'; z++) {
        std::cout << i << j << z << " ";
        totalIterations++;

        if (totalIterations > n-1) {
          return 0;
        }
      } 
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is undoubtedly helpful, but the question seems to be so lacking in personal effort and original research, that if the OP were to use this, they would probably be considered to be cheating based on the rules at their institution. On that basis, it is probably best to wait for folks to make their own effort before helping, so that they actually learn something.

Comment: Agreed, indeed it is, though wouldn't you agree that sometimes with programming you just need a little push in the right direction, especially when you're learning things. I'm sure the OP didn't mean any harm with her question and is probably pursued by a deadline and just needs to know how to get this problem done so she can move on.

Comment: I agree, but a full solution is probably not a "little push in the right direction", and that's the issue I am trying to tease out. If the OP uses this without understanding it, she may be less likely to go through the learning phases necessary to understanding it. Of course, we can hope that everyone here is willing to learn even though they have the answer, but my experience of reading hundreds of homework questions is that there are many students just seeking a shortcut.

Comment: (Educators are sometimes wise to this though - if they are impressed with a code solution they may ask a student to explain how it works, and if the student cannot explain it, they will probably be asked how they wrote code they cannot explain).

Comment: Thanks, I changed my answer in hopes that the OP will be encouraged a little bit before finishing with the exact solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your opinion. I was indeed looking for a little push a kind of advice or suggestion for example and not an entire solution to the problem. In now way would I want my question to be regarded as an attempt to cheat. I am simply quite new to this materia thus at times I find myself stuck on a task among the oceans of information available and unsorted. I am grateful to the author of the answer to my querry. I am going to get try my best to get to the bottom of it.